Is a HAVING condition with no aggregate always exactly equivalent to WHERE?
I recently ran across an interesting comment in the PostgreSQL test suite:
-- HAVING is effectively equivalent to WHERE in this case
SELECT b, c FROM test_having
    GROUP BY b, c HAVING b = 3 ORDER BY b, c;

It makes me think.  When a HAVING clause (or sub-clause) is referencing a non-aggregated value, is it always exactly functionally equivalent to WHERE?  Are there any cases where that is not true?  Given that the only non-aggregated references that are valid to appear in a HAVING clause are the GROUP BY key columns, it doesn't seem at first glance like it could filter out anything that would change the final result of the query.  But are there any possibilities I'm missing?

no not alwways, your example is onle the exception, as  having is processed after the group by you could get other responses as where as where is processed  before the groub by

@nbk Yes, I'm well aware of the processing order.  Can you give examples of where you could get different results, keeping in mind that it must still be a valid query?  (IE. no saying having Z = 10 when Z is not a GROUP BY column.)

I think that's true in general although I believe you could also use this at times to fake out the optimizer to delay filtering to a later stage of the query plan. Not sure that applies specifically to PostGres though.

@MasonWheeler with z would be valid, as onl columns in the SELECT can be chosen or aggregation functions, but for your simple sample, i could not find any solution that violates that assumption, i will nap over it

@MasonWheeler the only difference in you case would be the query efficiency (the results would be the same).  PostgreSQL states (Strictly speaking, you are allowed to write a HAVING clause that doesn't use aggregates, but it's seldom useful. The same condition could be used more efficiently at the WHERE stage

I could think of a possible exception. Where the values of  the grouping column that fall into a single group are in fact different then it will be non deterministic which one is returned. So the filter could potentially fail/succeed depending on which one is chosen. I tried to repro in SQL Server but that ended up just pushing the filter down to before the aggregation anyway https://dbfiddle.uk/8EGNb3mi

This stops it pushing the filter down https://dbfiddle.uk/0FmY4wYE

Postgres seems determined to push the filter down as though it was a WHERE and IMO returns the wrong result in the final query https://dbfiddle.uk/jlvW_FZj

@MartinSmith Interesting.  Has anyone reported that as a bug?

No idea. I haven't looked

@MartinSmith It's the wrong result, but not necessarily true that the result of 5 should be returned, because the actual grouping key is non-deterministic whether it picks the upper or lowercase version, so no rows at all is also a legitimate result. SQL Server does this correctly by the way https://dbfiddle.uk/k-jxDfJD

yeah - I already said above that it would be non deterministic which is chosen as the representative value of the group.  But whichever is chosen the COUNT(*) is definitely 5 and then the HAVING can either filter that out or not

The result will be the same - so you might argue that it's semantically the same.
But unless the DBMS has a very clever optimiser, using HAVING on a grouping column is a waste of resources:
In this query (re-formatting yours):
SELECT             
    b
  , c
FROM test_having
GROUP BY b, c 
HAVING b = 3 
ORDER BY b, c;


if b can assume a million values, the query will most probably group 999,999 buckets too many, only to discard them at the end; which it will not if you filter with WHERE before the GROUP BY .
ORDER BY b, c is a waste of time; how do you order one result row?


Yeah, it's a weird, wasteful query.  But this comes from Postgres's regression test suite.  By design, it's meant to be full of odd edge cases that the database needs to be able to deal with gracefully, rather than reflecting common usage.

Ordering a single row is common enough. Besides, there are still going to be multiple rows on c. I'm missing your point there.

How clever does an optimizer need to be? This has to be one of the easiest transforms don't you think?

When the HAVING clause references non-aggregated values that are also present in the GROUP BY clause, it behaves similarly to a WHERE clause. In your example, HAVING b = 3 could indeed be rewritten as WHERE b = 3, as it filters rows based on a non-aggregated value.
